# Geodesics on surfaces of centers of a surface

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, geodesic

Ex. 16 of Ch. 9 from the book "Differential Geometry", by A. V. Pogorelov, goes as follows:

> "The surfaces $F_1$ and $F_2$ are called the surfaces of centers of the surface $F$ if they are formed by the endpoints of segments of lenghts $1/\kappa_1$ and $1/\kappa_2$ ($\kappa_1$ and $\kappa_2$ are the principal curvatures of $F$), marked off on the normals to the surface $F$. A point correspondence is estalished in a natural way between the surfaces $F_1$, $F_2$ and $F$. Namely points on the surfaces lying on the same normal to F are corresponding points. Prove that geodesic curves on the surfaces of centers correspond to lines of curvatures on the surface $F$."

Some definitions and known results:

> A *line of curvature* is a curve on a surface such that its direction at every point is a principal direction. 
> A geodesic curve $\gamma$ on $X$ is a curve that satisfies $\gamma''//n$, where $n$ is the normal vector field associated to $X$. 
> Given a curve $\gamma$ on a surface $X$, its *geodesic curvature* is $\kappa_g(\gamma) := \gamma'' \cdot (n \times \gamma')$. 
> If $\gamma$ is a geodesic curve, then its geodesic curvature is equal to zero. 
> Locally, geodesics minimize distances on a surface.

My ideia was: Given a parametrization $r(u,v)$ of a neighborhood on $F$, we can induce parametrizations $r_1, r_2$ on $F_1$ and $F_2$, namely
\begin{align*}
r_1(u,v) = r(u,v) + \frac{1}{\kappa_1(u,v)}n(u,v), \\
r_2(u,v) = r(u,v) + \frac{1}{\kappa_2(u,v)}n(u,v).
\end{align*}
My intuition says I should find some relation between $n_1, n_2$ and $n$, and use the geodesic curvature result to get something, but I got nowhere. Maybe there's some special parametrization that would make things simpler, but I'm not sure. Does anybody have a clue on how to solve this?

(Of course, I'm always considering neighborhoods on $F$ such that both the principal curvatures are non-zero, so that $F_1$ and $F_2$ are well-defined)

Comment: Since we have no idea of the notation you use or the results/approaches you’re familiar with from the text, it would be helpful if you give as much of a proof as you can and then ask questions. For example, my natural approach to this would be to use the method of moving frames.

Comment: In addition, the statement accounts for two families of geodesics only, one on each $F_i$. Very misleading. Non-degeneracy conditions on the principal curvatures are obviously needed, as well.

Comment: @TedShifrin There you go

Comment: Yes, you should absolutely relate the normals to $F_i$ to the geometry of $F$. My suggestion with your approach is to assume there are no umbilics (which you need to assume, by the way, regardless) and take coordinates $u,v$ so that the $u$- and $v$-curves are the respective lines of curvature. Now calculate.